# gcov cannot open graph file

Tags: gcc, travis-ci, gcov

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `gcov` as part of my Travis CI build:

```
$ gcov src/bgrep.c
bgrep.gcno:cannot open graph file
```

My [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/bgrep/blob/add-coverage/.travis.yml):

```yml
language: c
compiler: gcc
sudo: false

before_script:
  - uname -a
  - printenv
  - gcov --version

script:
  - scons coverage=1
  - ls -l src/
  - test/run_test.py
  - ls -l src/
  - gcov src/bgrep.c
  - ls -l src/
  - ls -l

after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

I can run the exact sequence of commands (`scons`, `test/run_test.py`, `gcov src/bgrep.c`) on my Fedora machine, and `gcov` produces `grep.gcov` as expected.

Travis is using `gcov (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`. You can see an [example build log here](https://travis-ci.org/JonathonReinhart/bgrep/builds/98242206).

What am I (or Travis) doing wrong?

Comment: Could you run `find` as well?

Comment: This appears to be a difference in behavior between different versions of `gcov`. Apparently that of my newer Fedora is smart enough to find the data files when I give `gcov` a path like `src/bgrep.c`. Older gcov requires a `-o` option.

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean it's resolved?

Comment: Yeah. I'm eventually going to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with gcov and travis. It seems that gcov indeed requires that the *.gcda and *.gcno files must be in the same directory as the *.c files. And additionally the -o option must be given which points then to the same directory...

So, I have the source files in folder src/ and the binaries in build/coverage/. First, I tried with 'gcov -o build/coverage/ src/*.c' which did not work. Second attempt was with copying the *.gc* files to src/ and executing 'gcov src/*.c' which also did not work. It finally worked with 'gcov -o src/ src/*.c'.